# Can't update From Laravel 5.8 to 6.5.0

Tags: laravel, upgrade

i'm trying to upgrade Laravel to the latest release using Docker with 
php 7.2 
Ubuntu 16 
Laravel 5.8 and after the update when i try to run everything to do with `php artisan config:clear` or any `php artisan` i get :

> oot@88081fc77c2c:/data/www/html# php artisan cache:clear PHP Fatal
>   error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:804
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(804):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('config') #1
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(682):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config') #2
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(630):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array) #3
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(768):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array) #4
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1246):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config') #5
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php(62):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('config') #6
>   /data/www/html/vendor/aws/aws in
>   /data/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 806

**if i add this file in the boostrap/cache** as an return empty array, Laravel don't recognize view class, db class and on and on. Help please !!!!

P.S

```
1. added bootstrap/cache permissions
2. checked for empty spaces in the .env file
3. checked for , in the app/config.php file
```

Comment: Have you tried with `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Share your `.env` file with us

Answer (score 0):

In composer.json

```
"require": {

        "laravel/framework": "6.5.*",
            },
```

then

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, in the end i just found out thar my /bootstrap/app.php file contained some unnecessary provider (which should be in the providers place), and after cleaning it it worked out

> $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
>           realpath(**DIR**.'/../')
>       );
>
> ```
> $app->singleton(
>     Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
>     App\Http\Kernel::class
> );
>
> $app->singleton(
>     Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
>     App\Console\Kernel::class
> );
>
> $app->singleton(
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
>   App\Exceptions\PassportHandler::class
> );
>
> => removed : 
> $app->register(
>   Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class
> );
>
> return $app;
> ```